# Javascript Date Object ( New Object vs SetUTCDate ) getTime difference due to daylight savings

Tags: javascript, date

I have a while loop that selects dateCells inclusively that is now breaking due to daylight saving coming up and i'm wondering if there's a better way of fixing it.. (my plan is below the code)

```js
function doLoop(startDateObj, endDateObj){
  console.log("start: " + startDateObj)
  console.log("end: " + endDateObj)
  console.log("-----")

  var counterDateObj = new Date(startDateObj);
  while (true){
    if (counterDateObj.getTime()>endDateObj.getTime()){
      // hit! reached after end date

      console.log("=> hit");
      console.log("counter: "+counterDateObj)
      console.log("getTime(): "+counterDateObj.getTime()+" > "+endDateObj.getTime())

      break;
    };

    console.log(counterDateObj);
    counterDateObj.setUTCDate(counterDateObj.getUTCDate() + 1);
  };
};
```

Putting values before and after daylight savings throws the entire thing off:

```
doLoop(new Date('03/07/09'), new Date('03/10/09'));

VM2826:2  start: Sat Mar 07 2009 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
VM2826:3  end: Tue Mar 10 2009 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
VM2826:4  -----
VM2826:18 Sat Mar 07 2009 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
VM2826:18 Sun Mar 08 2009 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
VM2826:18 Mon Mar 09 2009 01:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
VM2826:11 => hit
VM2826:12 counter: Tue Mar 10 2009 01:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
VM2826:13 getTime(): 1236661200000 > 1236657600000
```

My current plan is: if it's greater than endDate timestamp + 5 extra hours in milliseconds, or something similar..

Can anyone think of a better way? My plan seems pretty ehhhh- not good

Comment: imagine it didn't say 2009 but 2020

Comment: Could you please summarise what you require?

Comment: Just anything to get the loop working correctly ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ Basically it shouldn't break on the 10th but the 11th. Is there a better way to add a day that doesn't shift the hours to 01:00:00? Is there a better if statement (besides the getTime() ) for checking if it's the next day?

Comment: You're mixing local and UTC date values, don't use UTC methods in `counterDateObj.setUTCDate(counterDateObj.getUTCDate() + 1)`.

Comment: **That was it!* so dumb.. I swear I changed it to UTC to deal with some other edge case but w/e. I appreciate it! (:

Comment: In most cases, you should work only in one or the other, don't mix them unless you know exactly what you're doing.